# Is there a more Pythonic way to pad a string to a variable length using string.format?

Tags: python, string.format

I want to pad a string to a certain length, depending on the value of a variable, and I'm wondering if there is a standard, Pythonic way to do this using the `string.format` [mini-language](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/string.html#formatspec). Right now, I can use string concatenation:

```
padded_length = 5
print(("\n{:-<" + str((padded_length)) + "}").format("abc"))
# Outputs "abc--"

padded_length = 10
print(("\n{:-<" + str((padded_length)) + "}").format("abc"))
#Outputs "abc-------"
```

I tried this method:

```
print(("{:-<{{padded_length}}}".format(padded_length = 10)).format("abc"))
```

but it raises an `IndexError: tuple index out of range` exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#41>", line 1, in <module>
    print(("{:-<{{padded_length}}}".format(padded_length = 10)).format("abc"))
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Is there a standard, in-built way to do this apart from string concatenation? The second method should work, so I'm not sure why it fails.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
print(("\n{:-<{}}").format("abc", padded_length))
```

The other way you were trying, should be written this way

```
print(("{{:-<{padded_length}}}".format(padded_length=10)).format("abc"))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. And here was me thinking I had read the documentation thoroughly enough when the answer was quite clear.

Answer (score 5):

The following example should provide a solution for you.

```
padded_length = 5
print("abc".rjust(padded_length, "-"))
```

prints:

```
--abc
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the outer most curly brackets. The following works fine for me:

```
>>>'{{0:-<{padded_length}}}'.format(padded_length=10).format('abc')
'abc-------'
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I wasn't thinking through which brackets needed to be escaped clearly enough.